# Where magical methods are coming from?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos

I have follow Objective-C code. But i am not understanding

- what is `alloc`, `init` in `Car *toyota = [[Car alloc] init];`?
- from where this method came from? `setModel`

// Car.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface Car : NSObject {
}

@property (copy) NSString *model;

- (void)drive;

@end
```

// Car.m

```
#import "Car.h"

@implementation Car {
  double _odometer;
}

@synthesize model = _model;

- (void)drive {
  NSLog(@"Driving a %@. Vrooooom!", self.model);
}

@end
```

// main.m

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "Car.h"

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
  @autoreleasepool {
    Car *toyota = [[Car alloc] init];

    [toyota setModel:@"Toyota Corolla"];
    NSLog(@"Created a %@", [toyota model]); // SQL: Insert into Car value 

    toyota.model = @"Toyota Camry"; // SQL: Update car set model=''
    NSLog(@"Changed the car to a %@", toyota.model);

    [toyota drive]; // SQL: Select *from Car

  }
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`alloc` and `init` are inherited from [`NSObject`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/objectivec/nsobject?language=objc), and they initialize your new `Car`. `setModel:` is auto-generated from your `@synthesize`d property `model` (and so is the method `model`, to get its value). You can override these methods to do extra work if you want. Also: in modern Objective-C, the property accessor ("dot") syntax is usually preferred over explicitly calling getter/setter methods.

Comment: Why they wrote the line `NSLog(@"Created a %@", [toyota model]);` but not as `NSLog(@"Created a %@", toyota.model );`?

Comment: you can access a property with the message sending mechanism as well

Comment: Yes, of course. The dot syntax is generally preferred, however.